# How to accept some struct as an output parameter?

Tags: c, parameters

## Problem

I want to be able to use a struct as an output parameter in C. Frustratingly, all of the articles I've found online for output parameters in C use primitives as examples. Since in general, C structs aren't easy to make deep copies, I'm scratching my head how to do this.  Take a look at this attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <glib.h>

void transform_pointer_contents(GArray** const arr) {
    GArray* const tmp = g_array_new(true, true, sizeof(uint8_t));
    const uint8_t example_num = 5;
    g_array_append_val(tmp, example_num);

    // Clear out the GArray contents
    if (*arr != NULL) {
        g_array_unref(*arr);
    }
    *arr = tmp;
}

int main() {
    const GArray* arr = g_array_new(true, true, sizeof(uint8_t));
    const GArray* evil_copy = arr;

    transform_pointer_contents(&arr);
    printf("Arr length is %d\n", arr->len);

    g_array_unref(arr);
}
```

## Elaboration

- It makes sense to me that one would want to clear out the old memory of the given output parameter `arr` before doing anything to it. And it seemed that using the intended creation functions was better than either:

  - trying to figure out how to do operations to get back to an initial state (e.g. deleting elements until empty)
  - setting the contents to zero
- It makes sense to me that functions should be resilient to junk being passed in by the caller (i.e. it shouldn't matter at all what value is sent to the function)
- The above code does leave open the possibility that the original pointer was copied and expected to still point to good memory, which could be really bad

## Question

- Is my reasoning that functions should handle junk accurate? Is it more important than the `evil_copy` problem?
- Is this a pattern which should be applied for all struct output parameters?

  - If not, what is the pattern for how to do this?

Comment: You need to free the memory that `arr` points to before overwriting it, otherwise you have a memory leak. Does `g_array_unref()` do that?

Comment: I think you should be getting an error about trying to update a `const` pointer.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it should be cleared if my understanding of the documentation is correct: https://docs.gtk.org/glib/type_func.Array.unref.html

Comment: This is a matter of API design. Both approaches (caller responsible for  clearing output param or function is responsible) are arguably valid. Like many things in computing this is a tradeoff between different uses cases. (I'm assuming you are using glib as an example and are really asking a general question).

Comment: @Barmar Since the GArray has a reference count of 1 to begin, inside the function should reduce it to 0, freeing the memory

Comment: @Barmar As to your comment that I'm updating a `const` pointer. I don't see where I am doing such a thing, the only pointer that is modified is one pointed to by `arr`, which isn't `const`

Comment: If you're using reference counting, callers are expected to call your API for making a copy, which will increment the refcount. If they don't, there's not much you can do about `evil_copy`.

Comment: `const GArray* const arr` makes `arr` constant. Doesn't `*arr = temp` in the function modify it?

Comment: The `evil_copy` problem is inherent in C. Higher-level languages address this with automatic garbage collection. C++ is intermediate with "smart pointers".